# How to swap places of a two eight-bit binary representations of an unsigned integer?

Tags: c, binary, bit

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void displayEightBits( unsigned int value );//prototype


int main(void){

 unsigned int x;

  printf( "%s", "Enter a nonnegative int: " );
  scanf( "%u", &x );
 displayEightBits( x );
}


void displayEightBits( unsigned int value )
{

 unsigned int c;

 unsigned int displayMask = 1 << 31;

 printf( "%10u = ", value );

 for ( c = 1; c <= 32; ++c ) {

   putchar( value & displayMask ? '1' : '0' );
   value <<= 1;

   if (c % 8 == 0 ){
    putchar( ' ' );
    }

   }

  putchar( '\n' );

 }
```

Hello, this program prompts the user for a non negative number and then returns two eight-bit binary representations of the number entered. I want to know how to swap where places swap their places. (i.e. move the left byte to right, and the right to left).

How to swap places of a two eight-bit binary representations of an unsigned integer?

Comment: Is this related to changing the endianness ??

Comment: Minor: Use `1u << 31` as `1 << 31` is technically a problem.

Comment: Did you want to reverse the bits, or reverse the bytes?

Comment: what do you mean by "two eight-bit binary representations"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an Array and put the last number as the first in the array

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understood the question correctly, you have:

```
00000000 00001111 11110000 11111111
```

and you want to have:

```
11111111 11110000 00001111 00000000
```

You need to have four for loops, one of which loops from 7 to 0, the second of which loops from 15 to 8, the third of which loops from 23 to 16 and the fourth of which loops from 31 to 24. Then if the loop variable is idx, you just do

```
putchar( value & (1<<idx) ? '1' : '0' );
```

Then just do

```
putchar(' ');
```

between the loops to keep the bytes separated by a space.

I'm not writing the full code for you, but based on these instructions you should be able to make a working program.

Edit: Ok, I wrote the code then if my answer was unclear. I hope this code makes my answer more clear:

```
unsigned value = 0x12345678U;
int idx;
for (idx = 7; idx >= 0; idx--)
    putchar(value & (1<<idx) ? '1' : '0');
putchar(' ');
for (idx = 15; idx >= 8; idx--)
    putchar(value & (1<<idx) ? '1' : '0');
putchar(' ');
for (idx = 23; idx >= 16; idx--)
    putchar(value & (1<<idx) ? '1' : '0');
putchar(' ');
for (idx = 31; idx >= 24; idx--)
    putchar(value & (1<<idx) ? '1' : '0');
putchar('\n');
```

Comment: I'm still a bit confused on what exactly your talking about with the for loops. Would you be so kind as to elaborate a little more on this statement, "7 to 0, the second of which loops from 15 to 8, the third of which loops from 23 to 16 and the fourth of which loops from 31 to 24." and what "(1<<idx) is?

Comment: (1<<idx) is the number 1 bit-shifted to the left by idx, i.e. the number 2 to the power of idx. If you don't understand what bit-shifting does, I recommend reading an elementary book about computers which explains how bit-shifting works. I edited my answer to give a code example.

Comment: If you just want to flip bits, like the bit patterns at the start of your answer, you'd just do `value = ~value;` (the `~` operator is bitwise NOT).

Comment: Ah, perhaps my example wasn't good. I asked whether the original poster wanted to rearrange the BINARYA, BINARYB, BINARYC, BINARYD binary strings into the order BINARYD, BINARYC, BINARYB, BINARYA. By a coincidence you could get the result by bitwise NOT for my particular example, but that's not what I meant.

Comment: the OP said that "move the left byte to right, and the right to left" which seems to be reversing the bytes